# nivo slider images are not appearing on ipod/iphone/ipad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, codeigniter, nivo-slider

I am using nivo slider in my codeigniter application and its working fine in all browsers,
but images are not appearing on ipad/ipod n iphone.

I have included 1.4.2.js inside html `<head>` tag and all images are of .png type.

Comment: Check if the image paths are correct, and check if nivo slider specific jqury files is loaded.

Comment: images path are correct.... jquery is properly loaded. it works well on safari,chrome,firefox,ie,opera but the problem is in mac n ipad.

Comment: links is confidential sorry @Fake Heal

Comment: Show us then how you load them in codeigniter? =)

Comment: <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
            <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
   
                <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>public/images/banner.png" alt="" />
    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>public/images/entertainment-banner.png" alt="" />
    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>public/images/img1.png" alt="" />
    
    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>public/images/other-banner.png" alt="" />
    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>public/images/sports-banner.png" alt="" />
    
   </div>
            
        </div>

Comment: Try using `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` instead of `'\'`. Even though I'm not sure that is your problem.
|| Try this: `<?=img(array('src' => 'public/images/banner.png', 'alt' => ''));?>`

Comment: still problem is not solved.... my slider images are having compatability issues with ios devices

Answer (score 1):

Nivo Slider is not natively compatible with iPhone/iPad - see [Gilbert's comment](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/2012/05/30/the-nivo-slider-is-responsive/#comment-736). However, it appears that MODJI [patched](http://modji.ca/blog/blog/nivo-slider-jquerymobile/) this.

Comment: hey well thanks all for your endless participation... but i have resolved this issue with the help of my designing team...as it was a mere 7-8 line changes in the main css file

Comment: [It's OK to answer your own question.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). Please let StackOverflow know what you did for future folks who may encounter this. Thanks!

Comment: in my container area i placed this code in my css file                        #container { width:1000px; background:#FFF; float:left;}

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to my article at http://tech.beacondeacon.com/nivo-superfish-issues.html for a solution if you are using something like Superfish menu along with Nivo Slider.  Basically, you have to disable superfish.js and only use hoverIntent.js and also disable the superfish() function call in the $(document).ready() function and change that to use $(window).load() instead.